# F5 SNI Passthrough

Tags: sni, f5-big-ip

G'day all,

I'm trying to configure an F5 virtual Big-IP for L4 pass through SNI load balancing, but am having troubles (probably because I'm new to F5's).

We have backend websites that require SNI (due to co-hosting multiple applications on a small set of servers).

I'd like to load balance (provide HA more correctly) to those servers from the F5 at the L4/TCP level, i.e. no SSL termination, no requirement to upload individual site certificates onto the F5 (Certs are issued by an internal CA, the root/intermediate certs are already available and trusted).

I was able to get this working fairly easily in HAProxy using a config that looks like:

```
frontend https
    mode tcp
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    use_backend api-uat if { req_ssl_sni -i api-uat.mydomain }
    use_backend api-prod if { req_ssl_sni -i api.mydomain }
    # repeat for other backends #

backend api-prod
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ api.mydomain 
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp

    server Server1 10.1.1.1:443 check check-ssl check-sni api.mydomain ca-file MyPKIRoot.pem
    server Server2 10.1.1.2:443 check check-ssl check-sni api.mydomain ca-file MyPKIRoot.pem

# repeat for other backends #
```

However [the documentation](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13452) on the F5 site is targeted at *hosting* using SNI (ie SSL termination on the F5, client profile ssl certs required).

Can any F5 gurus confirm if this is even possible?  As a side note [the SNI health check](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/https-sni-monitoring-how-to) for the back end servers is woefully underpar too, but I'll get to that once I can get the virtual server working correctly :(

Comment: https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13385

Comment: Thanks for that link, I hadn't found that yet.  That does require  "Importing the certificate and key pair that the destination server uses to the BIG-IP system." which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Since the first post I've also found [this page](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/sni-based-pool-selection-without-clientssl-profile-1119) which seems to do what I need.  I've implemented this and am correctly getting routed to my backend pools (per F5 logs and stats page), but I never get traffic _back_ when I attempt to connect (through curl or openssl)... I don't know whether to open another question for that or continue here...